# Sliding window over an interval on Esper

Tags: spark-streaming, esper

How do I achieve the same effect of Spark Streaming sliding window, which runs at X sliding interval over the last Y window length.

Looking at Esper, it should be `win:time` and `win:time_batch`, where win:time >= win:time_batch.

Answer (score 1):

In esper the equivalent is to declare a context.

```
create context BucketOf10Sec start @now end after 10 seconds;

context BucketOf10Sec select sum(price) from MyEvent;
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem in less customizable but easier way (at least for me), by using `win:time` with `OUTPUT EVERY x`

```
SELECT value
FROM Entry.win:time(10 sec)
OUTPUT EVERY 5 sec
```

Works as I intended - every 5 seconds I get results from the last 10 seconds.